# Records and multithreading, converting to pass through the wall

Tags: google-app-maker

First, is there an official CS term for sending things between the front end and back end? I just made up "the wall" but I would like a cooler term.

So in appmaker it seems you cannot pass whole records through to the backend (although you can handle them on either end).

So basically what I was doing was

get set of records, divide into chunks

```
var records = app.datasources.filesToProcess.items;
```

call backend process one time per chunk with this

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).backendProcess(records, start, end);
```

This allows for a kind of multithreading. The problem is passing records. Is there an easy way to get just the IDS from a set of records client side so I can pass those as an array in place of the records? Passing the record object itself gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
var records = app.datasources.filesToProcess.items.map(function(item) {return item.id;});
```

and then you can use

```
function backendProcess(records, start, end) {
  var items = app.models.YourModel.getRecords(records);
}
```

On the backend.

Comment: Amazing Markus, that map function is much more elegant than what I was hoping for.